# How can i make a search box to search by custom field

Tags: php, custom-field

Hy i am trying to make a search box for a week to search for post that have a specific custom field.

I have a post_type - **produse** with 2 custom field

- > CF1- culoare  / alb,maro,verde
- > CF2- marime   / 120x200, 200x300

Ok i want to make a checkbox form and select, after i select wath i want and push search i want to retrive the post that i have atached the custom field.

This i have made this from search around web.. but this is not working.. it load the cpu on my web hosting..

```
<?php 
$field = get_field_object('culoare');
$values = explode (',', $_GET['culoare']);
?>

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cauta dupa culoare:</legend>
        <?php if (!empty($field['choices'])) : $i = 0; foreach( $field['choices'] as $choice_value => $choice_label ): ?>
        <?php $culoareIndex = strtolower($choice_value); $i ++; ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="culoare" value="<?=$choice_value?>" id="checkbox-1-<?=$i?>" class="regular-checkbox-<?=$culoareIndex?>"
        <?php if( in_array($choice_value, $values) ): ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> />
        <label for="checkbox-1-<?=$i?>"></label>
         <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Functions.php

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) { return; }
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query'); // get original meta query

    // validate type
    if( (empty($_GET['culoare'])) )
    {
        return;
    }

    // get types as an array
    // - use explode to get an array of values from type=a|b|c
    $culori = explode('|', $_GET['culoare']);

    // set compare for the meta_query
    // - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
    $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';


    foreach( $culori as $culoare )
    {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'culoare',
            'value'     => '"' . $culoare . '"',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        );
    }


    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query); // update the meta query args

    return; // always return
}
```

Can somebody show me how is done,please, and point me in the right direction, i'm not so good with php and i want this to be made.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The generated SQL for that query is going to look something like:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id)
WHERE 1=1
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
  AND ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'culoare'
        AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%\"a\"%')
       OR (mt1.meta_key = 'culoare'
           AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%\"b\"%')
       OR (mt2.meta_key = 'culoare'
           AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%\"c\"%'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

There are three things you should notice. The first is that your query is generating an incorrect `LIKE` clause-- `'%\"c\"%'`. You do not want to quote your values when you create the `meta_query`.  Do simply:

```
'value'     => $culoare,
```

As you have it written, the query will search every row in the table but come up with nothing.

Secondly, `LIKE` queries, especially with wildcards-- the `%`s-- are not very efficient. The effects of that inefficiency are going to become more pronounced the larger your `$wpdb->postmeta` table becomes and the more conditions you try to match against.

Third, `LIKE` queries with an `OR` connector are not efficient. The query has to look at every row in the table to work out the result. Again, the effects of that inefficiency are going to become more pronounced the larger your `$wpdb->postmeta` table becomes and the more conditions you try to match against.

I suspect that those three problems are why this "load the cpu on my web hosting", by which I think you mean the server slows to a crawl and times out or crashes.

There is no simple solution.

- Try to add limiting conditions-- post dates, post authors, something
  to limit the scope of the search.
- Do you need the `LIKE` operator? An `=` or `IN` search would probably
  be quicker.
- Is there any way you can cache some of this information rather than
  run a search every time? If there is, you should pursue that avenue.